Missing CPU core temperatures
I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 24.04. Linux is not picking up the core temperature of the AMD Genoa 9334 ES + H13SSL-NT.
On Windows with fancontrol it detects the core temperature as well as the other motherboard CPU sensors. With lm-sensors Ubuntu is showing k10, but these appear to be the sensors on the motherboard. I have attached two images to show the difference in the sensors detected.
Has anyone any ideas as to how I can get Linux to detect the same temperature as on Windows for the core? I have read in many places k10 is the CPU temperature, but I know this not to be the case when testing under load.
Linux temperatures:

Windows temperatures:

lm-sensors is showing the package as k10. This is NOT the core    temperature of the CPU. The core temperature is available as it can be returned on Windows. Tested on Debian bookworm + Ubuntu 24.04.

Did you run sudo sensors-detect? And what was the result?

I think you misunderstood. I have already run it as you can see the completion of the command at the top of the screenshot before i execute sensors. Do you wish to see the output of the sensors-detect for the CPU?

Sorry, no doesn't matter. I don't know then..
